# ORACLE database - substr text from field without constant endpoint

Tags: oracle, substring

Is it real to get fragment of text in field if i don't know where it's end?
I have text with fragment like 'type work: blablabla' and need to get it.
Start point of fragment - 'type work:'

But length of it is not constant and after this fragment may be different other text - not constant delimiter like ; or , or something else which can give me endpoint for my fragment.

Examples:

> type work: blablabla
>
> start: 01-01-2019

***need to get***

type work: blablabla

OR

> type work: blablabla
>
> blablablabla
>
> sendornot:yes

***need to get***

type work: blablabla

blablablabla

Comment: you need a pattern. is `blablabla` always the same text? or how do you decide what text part do you Need?

Comment: @hotfix not, blablabla is not constant. Start point of fragment - 'type work:' text

Comment: Say you have something like" type work: xxx yyy some other field:yes"; how do you know whether some is the last word of the first text or first word of the following "tag"?

Comment: @Aleksej That's exactly my question. I know exactly where my fragment begins - it's 'type work:', but I don't know where it ends. The only thing for which I can catch that after the desired fragment is the next one, which is built around the same pattern - some text as a name of fragment and a colon. And this text after the fragment necessary to me is always. I. e. there are no cases when after the fragment necessary to me the text in the field comes to end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure but the following query might be what you need:

```
-- Sample data:
WITH dat(text) AS (SELECT 'type work: blablabla
start: 01-01-2019' FROM dual UNION ALL 
SELECT 'type work: blablabla
blablablabla
sendornot:yes' FROM dual)
-- Query:
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
          -- Make sure text starts with 'type work:':
          CASE WHEN INSTR(text, 'type work:') > 0 THEN SUBSTR(text, INSTR(text, 'type work:')) END
     , '(type work:[^:]*)'||CHR(10)||'[^:'||CHR(10)||']*:.*$','\1'
     ,1,1,'n') FROM dat
```

This query searches for the first : after `type work` and trades all of the line before that as key and then gets you the text from `type work` till that key.

If you have a list of the keys you might want to check for them instead of `[^:'||CHR(10)||']`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
          CASE WHEN INSTR(text, 'type work:') > 0 THEN SUBSTR(text, INSTR(text, 'type work:')) END
     , '(type work:[^:]*)'||CHR(10)||'(start|sendornot):.*$','\1'
     ,1,1,'n') FROM dat
```

Comment: Thank you, but problem that after my fragment may be several other fragments for example 
WITH dat(text) AS (SELECT 'type work: blablabla
start: 01-01-2019
end: 01-02-2019' FROM dual) it's not work

Comment: Okay you have to additionally set the match parameter 'n' so that the `.*` also matches the additional line breaks. Edited the answer accordingly...